# SQL concat multiple names and add dash in case of two names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation, names

I'm trying to figure out how to concatenate multiple names like last names and maiden names (including possible prefixes) as a full name without double spacing using a dash only when necessary (when one has two names).

For example:

- when a person has both a last name and a family name, I want it to appear like 
  `'A. van Dijk - Turner'` (note the dash, 'van de' are the prefixes)
- When a person has only a last or maiden name, I want it to appear like `'A van Dijk'`.

The following example code is definitely not sufficient:

```
concat (initals, ' ',prefixlastname,' ', lastname, ' - ', prefixmaidenname ', maidenname) AS 'full name'
```

If a person only has a maiden name, the code above results in e.g. 'A - van Dijk'.

What's the most efficient solution to this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i'm using SQL server 12.0.2

Answer (score 3):

Try something like `COALESCE(initals || ' ','')`, i.e. if initials is not null initials plus space is returned. If initials is NULL, then an empty string is returned.

Comment: Thanks, but the syntax is not accepted (incorrect syntax?). When I change it to single pipe, it doesn't work either (The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the '|' operator).

Comment: Perhaps, this is ANSI SQL syntax. I didn't notice the SQL Server tag until now, so I wrote a more or less dbms independent answer. Maybe coalesce(concat(initials,' '),'') works with SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows :

```
SELECT  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ISNULL(FirstName + '-','') + ISNULL(LastName + '-','')),2,8000))
```

Or another simpler version :

```
SELECT  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONCAT(FirstName +'-', LastName + '-') ),2,8000))
```

and whatever other columns you want

Comment: I keep getting the dash where I don't want to see it. Only in case of two names they should be separated by a dash.

Comment: With above query you must not see that annoying dash! :)

Answer (score 0):

my two cents:

COALESCE(familynameprefix + ' ' + familyname + ' - ', familyname + ' - ', '') + COALESCE(birthnameprefix + ' ' + birthname, birthname,'') Naam

## prerequisites:

- syntax is typically dutch
- birthname is the name you were born with: always exists
- familyname is the married name (applies to women only)
- this only works if the name of the man is only in the birthname

Coalesce looks for the first non-NULL value sequentially from left to right. If there is no name prefix, the next value is evaluated.